# Derivative of a convolution

Tags: convolution

I need to find the derivative of the following equation, which I do think is a convolution:

[image]

Could anybody give me a hint on how to find the derivative of V(x)?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: The derivative of a convolution is a convolution of one function with the derivative of the other, i.e. $y=x*f\Rightarrow y'=x'*f=x*f'$. So you need to apply this and chain rule.

Comment: I assume that you need to take the derivative with respect to x? If so, you pretty much have to integrate, then differentiate, since the integral is not from a constant to "x" (therefore the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus does not apply).

Comment: @ido I think it would be clearer if you had written $y = f*g \Rightarrow y' = f'*g = f*g'$.  In the OPs notation, $x$ denotes the variable with respect to which he differentiates.

Comment: @Torro How did you leap from $V(x)=k_1 \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(t)\cdot g(x-t)\;\mathrm{d}t$ to $V(x) = k_1(f\cdot g)(t)$?

Comment: @GrahamKemp that's the definition of a convolution:
$$
f * g (x) \equiv \int_E f(t) g(x - t) \, \mathrm{d} t
$$

Comment: @Danzimm The original image had $(f\star g)(\mathbf{t})$.  That's been corrected.

Comment: @GrahamKemp ah ok cool, sorry for the issue!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, let $\exists F(x,t): F_t(x,t)=\dfrac{\partial F(x,t)}{\partial t}, F_x(x,t)=\dfrac{\partial F(x,t)}{\partial x}, F_{x,t}(x,t)=\dfrac{\partial^2 F(x,t)}{\partial x\;\partial t}$

Specifically: $F_t(x,t)=f(t)\cdot g(x-t)$

$$\displaystyle \begin{align}\because \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d} x}\int_a^b F_{t}(x,t) \;\mathrm{d}t & = \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d} x}(F(x,b)-F(x,a)) \\ & =  F_x(x,b)-F_x(x,a) \\ & = \int_a^b F_{x,t}(x,t)\;\mathrm{d} t \\ & =\int_a^b \frac{\partial}{\partial x} F_t(x,t)\;\mathrm{d} t \\ \therefore \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d} x} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(t)\cdot g(x-t)\;\mathrm{d} t & = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(t)\cdot \frac{\partial\; g(x-t)}{\partial x} \;\mathrm{d} t \end{align}$$

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks for your replies.

Two questions:

1. Can I still apply Graham's derivation although dg(x-t)/dx in my case is NOT continous?
2. According to the other comments above, the following should also be allowed (in addition to Graham's derivation):

[image]

I can't really see that 2.) makes sense, since f(t) in a convolusion by definition never is a function of x and its derivative to x would always give 0. Could somebody maybe comment on this?!

Comment: Just watch the point of discontinuity. $\displaystyle \frac{\partial\;g(x-t)}{\partial\;x}=\frac{x-t}{\sqrt{R^2+(x-t)^2}} + \frac{|x-t|}{x-t} , \forall x\neq t$

Comment: 2. Let $h(z) = \dfrac{z}{\sqrt{R^2+z^2}} + \operatorname{sign}(z)$ then $\displaystyle\dfrac{\mathrm{d} V(x)}{\mathrm{d}x} = k_1\int_{\mathscr{E}} f(t)\cdot h(x-t)\;\mathrm{d} t = k_1 (f\star h)(x)$

Comment: Dear Graham, I am sorry, but I can not see the point of your answers. Could you maybe add some verbal explanation? Many thanks for your help.